# Memcached: Plugin Munin Error

Tags: memcached, munin

Good afternoon.

I'm trying to use memcached plugins and I'm getting errors when I use the command "munin-run" to test them.

The errors returned are:

```
Use of uninitialized value $ip in substitution (s///) at /etc/munin/plugins/memcached_hits line 28.
Use of uninitialized value $ip in concatenation (.) or string at /etc/munin/plugins/memcached_hits line 29.
Use of uninitialized value $port in concatenation (.) or string at /etc/munin/plugins/memcached_hits line 29.
Use of uninitialized value $ip in hash element at /usr/share/perl5/Cache/Memcached.pm line 253.
Use of uninitialized value $ip in index at /usr/share/perl5/Cache/Memcached.pm line 279.
Use of uninitialized value in subroutine entry at /usr/share/perl5/Cache/Memcached.pm line 288.
Bad arg length for Socket::pack_sockaddr_in, length is 0, should be 4 at /usr/lib/perl/5.14/Socket.pm line 260.
```

The lines 28 and 29 of memcached_hits plugin, refer to respective codes below:

```
$ip =~ s/_/./g;
my $address = "$ip:$port";
```

I'm having difficulty discovering a solution for this. Can anyone help me, kindly?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your memcached configuration file which probably resides here:

```
/etc/munin/plugin-conf.d/memcached
```

Looks something like this:

```
[memcached_*]
env.host 127.0.0.1
env.port 11211
env.timescale 3
```

Some default configuration files contain extra info  on the env lines like this:

```
# BAD! DELETE *default*
[memcached_*]
env.host 127.0.0.1  *default*
env.port 11211      *default*
env.timescale 3     *default*
```